# Problems encountered while creating csv files

Tags: python, csv

I want to create a csv file, it contains two columns, the first column is the label of the image, the second column is the address of the image, the following is my code:

```
import os
import os.path as osp
import sys
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import csv

data_dir = '/home/xieyangyang/Downloads/SiamFC/Data/VID/train/a'
video_names = os.listdir(data_dir)

for idx, video in enumerate(video_names):
    video_path = osp.join(data_dir, video)
    file_list = os.listdir(video_path)
    idex = idx
    for item in file_list:
        with open("test.csv","a+") as csvfile:
            idex = str(idex)
            src = osp.join(video_path, item)#addres
            #print(src)
            #print(idex) 
            writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
            writer.writerows([idex, src])
```

but csv is very is not normal:

```
['2', '0', '1']
['/', 'h', 'o', 'm', 'e', '/', 'x', 'i', 'e', 'y', 'a', 'n', 'g', 'y', 'a', 'n', 'g', '/', 'D', 'o', 'w', 'n', 'l', 'o', 'a', 'd', 's', '/', 'S', 'i', 'a', 'm', 'F', 'C', '/', 'D', 'a', 't', 'a', '/', 'V', 'I', 'D', '/', 't', 'r', 'a', 'i', 'n', '/', 'a', '/', 'c', 'a', 'r', '3', '7', '/', '2', '0', '1', '_', '0', '0', '5', '0', '7', 'v', '.', 'j', 'p', 'g']
```

but I want to it should be:

```
['1496', 'bounding_box_train/1496_c1s6_022396_05.jpg']
```

what should I do?

Comment: I I know what the problem is,I don't use the writer.writerows, I should change it to writer.writerow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**First problem:** In outer cycle you are reading images one by one, and inside of it you are opening csv file again and again for every image that you've read.

What should be done instead:

```
with open("test.csv","a+") as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    for idx, video in enumerate(video_names):
        ... write data ...
```

**Second problem:** You should use `writer.writerow([idex, src])` instead of `writer.writerows([idex, src])` (mind "s"). Second one (writerows) thinks, that you gave it two rows, one of which is **idex**, and another is **src**

Comment: further to this; I'd suggest opening the csv file at the top and doing all the writing while you've got it open once.  opening/writing/closing the file that many times is pretty slow, certainly much more so than iterating over `file_list`

Comment: I thought, that my solution to "First problem" does exactly what you've said, but now I'm beginning to doubt :)

Comment: you're right!  I was reading the OPs question and had mostly written an answer, then saw that you'd already covered most things, but somehow didn't actually read your code!

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice. I changed the code according to your requirements and found that the code execution efficiency was much higher

Answer (score 2):

if you remove the extra "s", it will work

```
        writer.writerows([idex, src])
```

Should be

```
writer.writerow([idex, src])
```

The function you are using is for an iterable, which is the reason it writes char by char in your output file.